# Cast String as Numeric in Find and Sort Operations

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection called `items`. I want to find the 10 highest priced items out of the active ones. My problem is the price is a string. So my question is how can I cast price as numeric and then sort the active items in descending order over price?

My current attempt gives me the highest price in alphanumeric order, i.e. 999. But I have items that are way pricier.

```
db.getCollection('items').find({"status": "active"})
.sort({"packet.price":-1})
.limit(10)
```

I tried:

```
sort({{$toInt:"packet.price"}:-1}),
```

```
sort({NumberInt("packet.price"):-1})
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with find method, you can use the aggregation framework,

- `$match` to match your query condition
- `$addFields` to change type of `price` field using `$toInt` operator
- `$sort` by `price` in descending order
- `$limit` 10 documents

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "active" }, },
  { "$addFields": { "packet.price": { "$toInt": "$packet.price" } } },
  { "$sort": { "packet.price": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

Comment: You need to name added field:
`{ "$addFields": {packetpriceint : { "$toInt": "$packet.price" } } },`
Then    
`{ "$sort": { "packetpriceint": -1 } },`

Comment: Ahh got it, thanks, just updated.